# How to avoid slash in collection name

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I am using http-source, mongo channel and NGSI mongosink for fiware cygnus. I want to avoid slash(/) in the collection name in mongodb. Is it possible by changing any fields of the configuration files? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance for all the support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fiware-cygnus mongodb storing collection name with /. How to use other separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622794/fiware-cygnus-mongodb-storing-collection-name-with-how-to-use-other-separator)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I'd say this issue is duplicated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622794/fiware-cygnus-mongodb-storing-collection-name-with-how-to-use-other-separator, isn't it?