# fiware-cygnus mongodb storing collection name with /. How to use other separator?

Tags: fiware-cygnus

When data is sent from orion borker.Cygnus creates the collection name with "/" is it possible to use any other separator. As for example, the entity name is room01 and entity type is room. Then the collection name becomes sth_/_room01_room. If it is possible how can I change the configuration? because I cannot use mongodump to creat backup of it.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation regarding slash in collection names in mongodump [is solved in MongoDB 4.0](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1163) so one possible solution is to use that version.

With regards to Cygnus, according to [NGSISTHSink](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/master/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_sth_sink/index.html#section1.3.2) and [NGSIMongoSink](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/master/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_mongo_sink/index.html#section1.3.2) documentation, what is called there the "new encoding" seems to avoid the slash in collection names (although the name will get somehow weird). In order to enable the new encoding you have to use the `enable_encoding` setting in the sink configuration.

Another possibility you could explore are [name mappings](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/master/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/name_mappings/index.html). This feature allows you to tune how the data is persisted. Not sure if it will allow you to avoid the slash in STH collection names, but it worth the time to have a look.